# Partial specialization or instantiation of template class method

Tags: c++, templates

I have template struct with several template parameters

```
template<class Result, class T, class K>
struct MyClass
{
public:
    Result foo()
    {
        return Result{};
    }
};
```

This struct works fine for all templates except the case when Result is void.
I understand, that `Result{}` cannot be implemented to void type, so my current solution is to use partial specialization like this:

```
template<class T, class K>
struct MyClass<void, T, K>
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        return;
    }
};
```

This allows to do following:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass<void, double, char> mycl1;
    MyClass<int, double, char> mycl2;

    mycl1.foo();
    mycl2.foo();
}
```

Is there a way to make `mycl1.foo()` compile without partial class specialization in C++ 14 standart? I could use `if constexr` and type trait `is_void_v` combination, but I want to find if there is a way to:

- specialization of template class method partial explicit
- instantiation of template class method

Comment: `void main()` is not valid, fixed that for you

Comment: @user463035818 won't the compiler complain that you aren't returning anything from main?

Comment: @Chipster `main` is the one exception where the `return` is optional, if you dont write it the compiler will `return 0;` for you

Comment: Using partial specialization of the class template seems to be a good strategy to me. Are you running into any problems while using it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you cannot do

```
Result foo()
{
    return Result{};
}
```

If `Result` is `void`, you can use

```
Result foo()
{
    return Result();
}
```

The behavior in this case is the same and you will get a value initialized object returned.  This syntax is allowed when `Result` is `void` by [[expr.type.conv]\2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.type.conv#2)

> If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding cast expression. If the type is cv void and the initializer is (), the expression is a prvalue of the specified type that performs no initialization. Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized with the initializer. For an expression of the form T(), T shall not be an array type.

Coming soon though you will be able to use

```
return Result{};
```

even if `Result` is `void` as C++20 added to that section that `{}` will work as well for `void`.  [[expr.type.conv]\2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type.conv#2) now states

> If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression. Otherwise, if the type is cv void and the initializer is () or {} (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a prvalue of the specified type that performs no initialization. Otherwise, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type whose result object is direct-initialized with the initializer. If the initializer is a parenthesized optional expression-list, the specified type shall not be an array type.

Comment: daaaaaaaaaaaaamn, thanks so much. 
Usually I avoid using () for constructors, but in this case I have to use it

Comment: @Demaunt Yeah, unfortunately uniform initialization is exactly uniform.  Thankfully this case is being fixed.

Comment: one more example for the uniformity of uniform initialization ;)